# Conditional usage of Optional Parameter

Tags: c#-4.0, boolean, .net-4.5, optional-parameters

I have the classes :

```
public class Result{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Category {get; set;}
    }

public SearchResults {
    public string PageNum {get; set;}
    public string PageSize {get; set;}
    public string TotalCount {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Result> Results {get; set;)
    }
```

I have the method:

```
public SearchResults GetSearchResults(bool full = false)
{
    return new SearchResults {
       PageNum = 1,
       PageSize = 25,
       TotalCount = 100,
       Results = new[] {new Result {Name="Alpha", Category="Bravo"}}
      // return Results only if parameter [full] is true ???How
    };
}
```

In the above method, I want to return [Results] only if the [full] parameter is true. And by default not return it.

Comment: What do you want to return if full is false?

Comment: How is this method supposed to be useful then?  Just remove the argument, the caller can simply not call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) and return `null` for result like:

```
Results = full ? new[] { new Result { Name = "Alpha", Category = "Bravo" } } : null,
```

By default since `Result` is a property it will be assigned `null` *(default)*.

So your method would be like:

```
public SearchResults GetSearchResults(bool full = false)
{
    return new SearchResults
    {
        PageNum = 1,
        PageSize = 25,
        TotalCount = 100,
        Results = full ? new[] { new Result { Name = "Alpha", Category = "Bravo" } } : null,
    };
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to not return the property itself instead of assigning it null?

Comment: @GilliVilla, what do you mean by returning the property itself? you are returning a new object of type `SearchResults`

Comment: When I return the new object and [full] is false I do not want [Results] to appear in the [SearchResults]. Instead of [Result = null] is there a way that now [SearchResults] behaves as if it didn't have [Results] to begin with?

Comment: @GilliVilla, No you can't do that, you have to create two separate classes with one having a `Result` property and other without it.